# Suggested order of using graph conversion tools in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

TensorFlow has some different utilities which can modify the frozen graph such as `optimize_for_inference`, `quantize_graph` and `convert_graphdef_memmapped_format`. If we want to use more than one of these conversions, is there any order which should be followed? Is the final output file going to be the same regardless of the order?